# How to insert row with an auto increment column SQLite

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, database, sqlite

I downloded a MySQL database and parse it to SQLite using this PHP [script](https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776).

I use the SQLite database on WPF and i am able to make some operations using this [library](http://www.janaks.com.np/using-sqlite-in-wpf-application/). The problem is that i tried to execute an INSERT in a table with an auto increment field and it is not working, here is my query:

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=test.db");
conn.Open();
var command = conn.CreateCommand();

command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tickets(created, user) values ('2015-12-12', 345)";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Here is my table *tickets* at the .db:

```
CREATE TABLE "tickets" (
  "id" int(11) NOT NULL ,
  "user" int(11) NOT NULL,
  "created" timestamp NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
)
```

At MySQL my query works perfect and my *id* column always get the next auto increment value, but in SQLite i can't get this value to autoincrement. When i run the app it crashes with the next message:

> Additional information: constraint failed
>
> NOT NULL constraint failed: tickets.id

I know the value should not be null, but it should be auto incrementing... is this possible?

Comment: where you specified that the field `id` is auto increment?

Comment: @un-lucky I specified the autoincrement value on MySQL, but the parser didnt added

Comment: Here is the answer and a full explanation of this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744711/mysql2sqlite-sh-auto-increment

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the field `id` as auto increment at the time of creation of the table;

Take a [look](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_autoincrement.htm):

```
 CREATE TABLE "tickets" (
 "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT,
 "user" int(11) NOT NULL,
 "created" timestamp NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should mark your column with AUTO INCREMENT keyword as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE tickets(
   ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT,
   USER           INTEGER      NOT NULL,
   CREATED            TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL
);
```

Source: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: @Fernando-Santiago was this answer helpful for you? you can mark it as answer if it was !